# Show access restricted pages within Viewhelper "v:page.menu" (Fluid Powered TYPO3)

Tags: menu, typo3, fluid, access-rights, viewhelper

In my TYPO3 project, I create a page menu with the vhs extension viewhelper v:page.menu.

Problem is, access restricted pages are hidden in this menu - but I need them to be shown.

I know that there is a way to do this in a typoscript menu:

```
lib.mainMenu {
1 = TMENU
1 {
showAccessRestrictedPages = 100
showAccessRestrictedPages.addParams = &return_url=###RETURN_URL###&pageId=###PAGE_ID###
...
```

But can I somehow get the same result with the viewhelper? Or do I have to create a typoscript menu for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Supported in VHS since version 3.0, through use of the `showAccessRestricted`, `classAccessGranted` and `classAccessProtected` arguments.